# MVC form Post null at controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Building a form that allows user to add infinite lines. This is done with ajax call to controller that adds a partial view (one time per click).

I am using Html.BeginCollectionItem to index each input in the partial views.

I can add a bunch of items and click submit, I can see the form is posted in fiddler, but the controller shows a null form.  If I change the post controller type from List<> to singular AccessoryVM, I get the first item.

I have tried swaping the model type in the Index view from List to IEnumerable, no change.

Index:

```
@model List<EmployeeHardwareRequest.Models.ViewModels.AccessoryVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Select Accessories";
}

<h2>Accessories</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Accessory", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div id="form-body">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_NewItem")
            }
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button id="add-item" class="btn btn-primary">Add Another Item</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" value="Select Software" class="btn btn-default pull-right" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Partial:

```
@model EmployeeHardwareRequest.Models.ViewModels.AccessoryVM

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedAccessory, Model.AccessoryDdl, new { @class = "form-control accessoryList" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("AccessoryVM"))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductLink, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter link to web page" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <button type="button" id="deleteItem" class="btn btn-danger">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Controllers:
Index:
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List modelList = new List();

```
        List<Accessory> accessories = _db.Accessory.ToList();  // change this to use the accessoryDTO

        List<int> monitorSizeList = new List<int>  // replace this with data from db table.
        {
            20, 22, 24, 27
        };

        model.AccessoryDdl = new SelectList(accessories, "AccessoryId", "ItemDescription", selectedAcc);
        model.MonitorSizeDdl = new SelectList(monitorSizeList);
        return View(modelList);
    }
```

Get partial view:

```
    public ActionResult AddItem(int index)
    {
        AccessoryVM model = new AccessoryVM();
        int selectedAcc = 1;

        List<Accessory> accessories = _db.Accessory.ToList();  // change this to use the accessoryDTO

        List<int> monitorSizeList = new List<int>  // replace this with data from db table.
        {
            20, 22, 24, 27
        };

        //model.lineIndex = index++;

        model.AccessoryDdl = new SelectList(accessories, "AccessoryId", "ItemDescription", selectedAcc);
        model.MonitorSizeDdl = new SelectList(monitorSizeList, "Select Monitor Size");
        return PartialView("_NewItem", model);
    }
```

post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<AccessoryVM> form)
    {
```

I have checked for double use of keywords and properties, but don't see any conflicts.

Comment: Basically, the problem is that at submit you are submitting List<AccessoryVM> which excepts the model binding name as [0].SelectedAccessory, [0].ProductLink, [1].SelectedAccessory, [1].ProductLink....................... However, the partial view generates same name SelectedAccessory and ProductLink for each row. This breaks the model binding. To fix it, either you can create a list at js to push data from each row and post it to server or generate the input control name in partial view as required for model binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this in your post function

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(List<AccessoryVM> form)
 {
    foreach (var AccessoryVM in model.AccessoryVMs)
    {
       //do stuff with each of these here ..
    }
  }
```

Regards
Jasbeer Singh